# eigenvector and eigenvalue of a matrix with python

Tags: python

#how to find the eigen value and eigen vector of a matrix using python when the elements contain some variable than actual number ?

```
   from sympy import *
   from numpy import matrix
   from numpy import linalg
   from sympy import Matrix
   import numpy as np 
   m,c,k = symbols('m,c,k')
   A = Matrix( [[0, 0, m,0],[0, 0, 0,2*m],[m,0,0,0],[0,2*m,0,c]])
   B = Matrix( [[-m, 0, 0,0],[0, -2*m, 0,0],[0,0,3*k,-2*k],[0,0,-2*k,2*k]])
   A_inverse = A.inv()
   a = np.array(A_inverse)
   b = np.array(B)
   m= np.matmul(a, b)
   print(B)
   print(A) 
   print(A_inverse)
   w, v = linalg.eig(m) ###this does not work!!!`
   print("w:",w)
   print("v:",v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think numpy integrates like that with sympy, however, sympy has built in diagonalization methods, you could try the following

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
from sympy import Matrix
import numpy as np 
m,c,k = symbols('m,c,k')
A = Matrix( [[0, 0, m,0],[0, 0, 0,2*m],[m,0,0,0],[0,2*m,0,c]])
B = Matrix( [[-m, 0, 0,0],[0, -2*m, 0,0],[0,0,3*k,-2*k],[0,0,-2*k,2*k]])

(P,D) = A.diagonalize()
```

then you can type D in the ipython console and it will display the latex visualization of the answer